# json jq array to string with double quotes

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am trying to convert an array to string and would like to be:

```
declare -r LOCAL_VERSIONS=(
    "1.3.17"
    "1.3.18"
    "1.3.19"
    "1.3.20"
    "1.4.0-beta.1"
    "1.4.0-beta.1"
    "1.4.0-beta.2"
    "1.4.0"
    "1.4.1"
    "1.4.2"
    "1.4.3"
    "1.4.4"
    "1.5.0-beta.1"
    "1.5.0"
    "1.5.1"
    "1.5.2"
)
```

The best I got so far is:

```sh
declare -r VERSIONS=(=${VERSIONS:-$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/humhub/humhub/releases | jq -r '.[] | [.name] | join(" ")')})
```

which outputs:

```
1.5.1
1.5.0
1.5.0-beta.1
1.4.4
1.4.3
1.4.2
1.4.1
1.4.0
1.3.20
1.3.19
1.4.0-beta.2
1.3.18
1.4.0-beta.1
1.3.17
1.3.9
1.3.8
1.3.7
1.3.6
1.3.5
1.3.4
1.3.3
1.3.2
```

How I can achieve as LOCAL_VERSIONS using curl (meaning getting versions from GitHub) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-r` in `jq -r` removed quotes, this is what's needed :

```
declare VERSIONS=($(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/humhub/humhub/releases | jq '.[].name'))
```